# How to solve Inequality with factorials

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods, factorial

Im reading a book in Numerial analysis and I have the following which I dont understand involving inequalities and factorials, What i have is the following:

$$\frac{1}{(2n+1)!(2n+1)} \leq 5*10^{-9}$$

The book gives the answer $2n+1 \leq 11$, so $n \geq5$, but i dont know how the procedure.
As an example what would be the value of $n$ so that the following holds:
$$\frac{1}{(2n+2)!(2n+1)} \leq 5*10^{-9}$$ Using matlab i found that n $\geq 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(n) = \frac{1}{(2n+1)!(2n+1)}
$$
we know that 
$$
f(n+1) < f(n)
$$
i.e. strictly decreasing function with $n$.
thus trying a few values of $n$ we find 
\begin{align}
\text{n=4:  } \frac{1}{9!9} &=& \frac{1}{3265920}\approx 3\times10^{-7}\\
\text{n=5:  } \frac{1}{11!11} &=& \frac{1}{439084800}\approx 2\times10^{-9}\\
\text{n=6:  } \frac{1}{13!1} &=& \frac{1}{80951270400}\approx 1\times10^{-11}\\
\end{align}
thus we can conclude that your limit lies between $5 < n <6$ thus the highest integer is $n=5$ you can do the same for the other function.

I preface this with the fact that you may have to use a "more" mathematical approach than just trying values. i.e. I determined by using $n$ but you give a relation $2n+1 \leq 11$ to derive your $n$, so you may have to use a different approach.